# How to use exported webflow code in ReactJS/NextJS?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js, webflow

I have exported my webflow code to my NextJS app, however a lot of the HTML tags show up as errors (it says most of them don't have closing tags).

Does anyone have any idea why this is and what I can do to solve this? NOTE: The Webflow code is relatively simple with no animations, etc.

Also, the code works fine when viewed in index.html

Comment: How exactly are you trying to use the exported HTML in Next.js? If you have whole HTML files you could use the approach described in [How do you serve a static site (like from Webflow or a landing page generator) in Next JS on Vercel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66477888/how-do-you-serve-a-static-site-like-from-webflow-or-a-landing-page-generator-i).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely the way Webflow exports some tags without closing slashes. Next.js require these slashes to properly parse the tags.

For example, Webflow might export the following code:

```
<img src='/' alt=''>
<input type='text' name='name'>
```

To fix this, you just need to add the closing slashes to the end of each tag, like this:

```
<img src='/' alt='' />
<input type='text' name='name' />
```

By adding the slashes, you're telling Next.js that each element is properly closed, which should help resolve any issues you're experiencing.

Here is a list of HTML tags that should be self-closed with an ending slash in Next.js:

```
<br />
<hr />
<img />
<input />
<link />
<meta />
```

Hope this helps.